# PLSQL script that does gcd beetween all possible pairs of numbers in a randomly generated table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have to create a table with 10 entries, filled with random values from 20-100. The numbers must be distinct. Then I must create a second table, filled with the greatest common denominator between all possible pairs, (x,y),where x,y are numbers from the first created table. This is what I have thus far:

```
                DROP TABLE random;
               CREATE TABLE random
                (
                 numbers int
                );

               DECLARE
               numberToInsert int;
                i int:=0;
               CURSOR c_random is select trunc(dbms_random.value(20,100)) from dual;
               BEGIN
               LOOP
               open c_random;
               i:=i+1;
               fetch c_random into numberToInsert;
               INSERT INTO random VALUES (numberToInsert);
               close c_random; 
               EXIT WHEN i = 10;
               END LOOP;
               END;
               /
```

So this inserts into table random 10 different random numbers from 20-100. The numbers are however not always distinct. And I don't know how to do the second part. Obviously I need to use a while loop and do Euclid algorithm. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select x, y
from(
  select 19+level as x
  from dual
  connect by level <= 200-19
) cross join (
  select 19+level as y
  from dual
  connect by level <= 200-19
)
order by dbms_random.value()
fetch first 20 rows only;
```

The query generates two sets of numbers from 20 to 200, then combine these two set using cross jon - this gives a distinct set of pairs X,Y coming from both sets
In the end the query uses "order by random" and picks 20 random rows.
`FIRST 20 ROWS ONLY` clause works on Oracle 12c, on earlier versions you need to convert this query into a subquery and use `WHERE rownum <= 20`
To insert a result into the table, use simple:

```
INSERT INTO table ...
SELECT ....the above query....
```

---

> which part of the query insures the numbers are distinct?

Well, the **CROSS JOIN** guarantes that.
If two **distinct** sets are combined using the cross join, a result also will be **distinct**. This is how a join works - it combines all rows from one table with all rows from the other table.
Please take a look at the below simple example, the result **is distinc**:

```
select x, y
from(
  select 19+level as x
  from dual
  connect by level <= 22-19
) cross join (
  select 19+level as y
  from dual
  connect by level <= 22-19
)
        X          Y
---------- ----------
        20         20 
        20         21 
        20         22 
        21         20 
        21         21 
        21         22 
        22         20 
        22         21 
        22         22
```

Comment: which part of the query insures the numbers are distinct?